# How do I pull specific responses only from the list item I modified and send those responses in an automated email?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, modified

I have a list of items for individuals to investigate.  I would like an automated email to generate when one of the list items has a status change from pending to investigating, and to identify the list item that individual is investigating in the notification email.